# Getting the inserted character and the position at which it was inserted from textarea in React

Tags: html, reactjs, web, textarea

What I want is a textarea (or any input taking element for that matter) in react to provide the following:

- When a new character is inserted - get the character inserted and the position it was inserted at.
- When a character is deleted - get the position of the character that was deleted.

I was thinking along the lines of using onChange and onKeyDown/Press together, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go about this. I could also do a diff on the initial text and the final text, but that is slow.

I am also open to using any open source libraries to achieve this. I am basically trying to make a text editor and want this information available to me when a user is working on the editor.

Comment: You will probably need to compare previous state with new value and find, what changed because input's onChange event is providing you a new input's value not only the characters that was changed

Comment: I know, but that will be super slow, is there no other way to do this? I was thinking of using the onKeyDown event to receive the key that was pressed and then get the current cursor position to get the position of insert. But I do not know if that will work for different keyboard layouts.